# unexpected token: 'Map'

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my test class

```
@isTest
private class TestClozer {

    static testMethod void myTest() {

        PageReference pageRef = Page.clozer;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);   

        system.assertEquals(ApexPages.currentPage(),pageRef);  

        Search sh = new Search();
        Map<String, String> countryList = sh.loadCountryData();
        system.assertNotEquals(null,countryList);    

        for(String c: countryList.keySet())
        {
            Map<String, Search.ClsCity()> cityList = loadCityData(countryList.get(c));
        }

    }
}
```

And ive a inner class on Search class thats called 'ClsCity'
Ive no idea why this happen
Thanks in advance

Comment: not working bro

Comment: Map<String, Search.ClsCity> cityList = loadCityData(countryList.get(c));

Comment: @SanderdeJong i got this Method does not exist or incorrect signature: loadCityData(String)

Comment: Where is that declared? If in class XYZ, then call XYZ.loadCityData(String) And does it return a Map?

Answer (score 4):

In execute anonymous this:

```
Map<String, Search.ClsCity()> cityList;
```

produces the:

> unexpected token: 'Map'

error. Remove the `()` (which signifies method invocation) to leave just the name of the class:

```
Map<String, Search.ClsCity> cityList = ...;
```

Comment: but now im facing
"Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts"

Comment: @moinkhan OK. That is a different issue that you can Google an explanation of. Very common to have layers of problems in code that you just need to work through one by one.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create a Mock class and then have to use this class to make fake callout from Test class to cover your coverage, as Callout from Test classes is not supported in salesforce.

Here is the link to crate MockTest class.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm